# How to list variables accessible in a Jade template?

Tags: node.js, express, frameworks, pug, templating

Everything is in the title, it is for debugging purposes!

Thank you by advance, I have no idea how to manage it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span.debug #{Object.keys(locals)}`

you can try out some own things on the old demo site: http://jade-lang.com/demo/